# GitLab - reference file line/lines range with snippet in issue

Tags: gitlab

GitHub can do that, but I'm not able to find the same on GitLab.
Does GitLab currently support this functionality?

Answer (score 13):

From the GitLab documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#gitlab-specific-references:

> [README](doc/README#L13) repository file line references

From trying out myself:

```
[README](doc/README#L13-22)
```

will reference a line range. GitLab EE 11.5

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't show a preview. It is just a link.

Comment: You asked about a "reference", which is a link.

Comment: I think it's not supported in GitLab right now. GitHub only introduced it in August 2017 themselves: https://blog.github.com/2017-08-15-introducing-embedded-code-snippets/

Comment: Thanks. It's a pity, it is really useful

Comment: @YetiCGN This was my experience as well, it highlights the range but the documentation doesn't mention that behavior. I'm on Gitlab CE 14.0.6.

Comment: What's annoying is that if the file changes, the referenced line numbers don't. So if you make an issue, then somebody merges in changes that change that file, the referenced lines in the issue will then be incorrect.

Comment: @ChrisCrossCrash This is a not a problem if you use a permalink.